# Replace within a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, replace, common-table-expression

I have an XML field that I need to remove a rogue rode from.
That rogue node is

```
<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>


With CTEScreenXML (Code, CreatedOn, ScreenXML) AS
(
    SELECT GXML.Code, GXML.CreatedOn, CAST(GXML.ScreenXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
    From dbo.GenScreenXML GXML
    WHERE CAST(GXML.ScreenXML AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) like '%<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>%'
)

SELECT REPLACE(CTEScreenXML.ScreenXML, '<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>', '')) --THIS LINE
FROM CTEScreenXML
```

How do I address the CTEScreenXML.ScreenXML Field on line marked in order to do the replace?

This CTE will have approx 300 rows so the replace needs to work on all 300 rows.

Comment: `FROM dbo.CTEScreenXML`?  CTEs don't have a schema; this query would throw an error.  Beyond that and the extra close parenthesis on the SELECT line and the unnecessary WHERE clause in the outer query, this looks just fine.  Are you using case-sensitive collation possibly?  What does your data look like?  What does your result look like?  What are you expecting the result to look like?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's the problem when using your current query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide an alias name for the formatted or changed columns in your CTE. Try this:

```
With CTEScreenXML (Code, CreatedOn, ScreenXML) AS
(
    SELECT GXML.Code, GXML.CreatedOn, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),GXML.ScreenXML) [ScreenXML]
    From dbo.GenScreenXML GXML
    WHERE CHARINDEX('<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),GXML.ScreenXML))>0
)
SELECT REPLACE(ScreenXML, '<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>', '')) --THIS LINE
FROM dbo.CTEScreenXML
```

OR

```
SELECT GXML.Code, GXML.CreatedOn, REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),GXML.ScreenXML), '<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>', '') [ScreenXML]
FROM dbo.GenScreenXML GXML
WHERE CHARINDEX('<PROMPT><span/></PROMPT>',CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),GXML.ScreenXML))>0ONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),GXML.ScreenXML))>0
```

Answer (score 0):

If **ScreenXML** is an XML column type, I'd suggest querying for the node(s) you want to remove and [delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx) it, rather than casting it to NVARCHAR and comparing a string of characters.

for example:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml   
SET @myDoc = SELECT CTEScreenXML.ScreenXML FROM CTEScreenXML
SET @myDoc.modify('delete //Prompt/')
```

after set: @myDoc will contain the original XML without any Prompt elements.

For more examples, read up on [XQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189919.aspx) expressions.